# Use EDMX designer with PostgreSQL

Tags: entity-framework, postgresql, devart, dotconnect

Is there a way to use my existing EDMX and connect to PostgreSQL ?

Also can I convert MSSql edmx to work with postges, coverting edmx to edmi is also an option?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to use my existing EDMX and connect to PostgreSQL ?

The only option is to remove the current connection string from the config file of the application. After that, when running any of the wizards in the EDM Designer, the dialog box for choosing/creating the connection will be shown first.

> Also can I convert MSSql edmx to work with postges, coverting edmx to edmi is also an option?

Yes, it is available. You can open an *.edmx file in Entity Developer and save it as *.edml for further work. After you have converted your model you  can change the connection being used to the necessary one (open Database Explorer,  right-click the Database Connection and select Edit Connection  Properties from the shortcut menu).
JIC: dotConnect for PostgreSQL Professional should be installed.

Entity Developer has a lot of improvements comparing to EDM Wizard (*.edmx, the ADO.NET Entity Data Model item):

1. Visual editing of the storage part of the model
2. Embedded T4 Editor for customizing templates: http://www.devart.com/entitydeveloper/code-generation.html
3. Handy EF Code First DbContext Template: http://blogs.devart.com/dotconnect/entity-developer-ef-code-first-dbcontext-template.html
4. Splitting a model into diagrams to improve its readability: http://blogs.devart.com/dotconnect/working-with-large-models-and-oracle-autoincrement-fields-in-new-version-of-entity-developer.html
5. Data viewing/editing: http://www.devart.com/entitydeveloper/data.html
6. Visual enhancements: http://blogs.devart.com/dotconnect/visual-enhancements-in-entity-developer-4-1.html
7. All advanced Entity Developer functionality is available in all supported Visual Studio versions: 2008 - 2013
8. The possibility of configuring data type mapping using Database-First approach
9. Wide range of settings for naming rules for model objects
10. The possibility to enable the synchronization of mapping and storage parts when editing the conceptual part

Please refer to http://www.devart.com/entitydeveloper/ed-vs-edm.html